# how to make jquery.tabs takes <li> name instead of <a> href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is an example of what i need to achieve when i click on a `<li>` i want to change the tabs instead of clicking on `<a>` i need it for a reasons is there is a way to achieve that

```
<script>
   $(function() {
     $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

   });
   </script>

    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li name='tabs-1'>tab1</li>
            <li name='tabs-2'>tab2</li>
            <li name='tabs-3'>tab3</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">...</div>
        <div id="tabs-2">...</div>
        <div id="tabs-3">...</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You mean you want to change tabs by clicking on `<li>` instead of clicking on `<a>`, right?

Comment: something like that

Comment: but please make a notice that there is no limit of `<li>` number they may be 10 or 3 as the `<div>` as well

Comment: why not add a tags and then make li a{display:block;} and you can then click the whole li to perform your query.

Comment: because i'm using 3d effect with content and i change from `<a>` to `string content` on `mouse hover`

Comment: i update my question code please recheck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTab li:last').tab('show')
});
```

```css
.nav-tabs li {
  margin:10px;
   padding:10px;
   backgroung-color:#c2c2c2;
   border-left:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
     <li class="active" data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</li>
     <li data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</li>
     <li data-target="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</li>
     <li data-target="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</li>
   </ul>

   <div class="tab-content">
     <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home</div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile</div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Message</div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">Settings</div>
   </div>
```

Hope above solution meet your requirement

Comment: can it still workds if i don't use `class='nav nav-tabs'`?

Comment: because i already have style
but i'm using it as`<nav class='Nav'><ul> <li></li>......</ul></nav>`

Comment: You can remove this class="nav nav-tabs" if you have your style already- This won't stop functionality.
But don't remove data-target and data-toggle attributes from li's

Answer (score 0):

Since I understood you want to change tabs by clicking on `<li>` instead of clicking on `<a>`, maybe this will work:

```
$("li").on("click", function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr("name");
    $("#tabs div").each(function(){  //Hide all tabs
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $("#"+tab_id).show(); //Show tab
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The "a" tag is an inline level element. No inline level element may have its width set. Why? Because inline level elements are meant to represent flowing text which could in theory wrap from one line to the next. In those sorts of cases, it doesn't make sense to supply the width of the element, because you don't necessarily know if it's going to wrap or not. In order to set its width, you must change its display property to block, or inline-block:

Just style the A with a display:block;:

```
#yourselector ul li a { display: block;}
```

Comment: means, you just want to click on outside of text.